# Creating a shortcode based on users preferences

Tags: shortcode

Background: Creating a dynamic shortcode based on user inputs. This shortcode should change the output of `do_shortcode` based on the fields the user selects.

Example: On a page, a user selects

> "Show me:  (X) Skateboarding (X) Basketball ( ) Hockey"

When they click submit, the shortcode to do this should show as:

```
[shortcode_name types="Skateboarding, Basketball"]
```

and since Hockey wasn't selected, Hockey wouldn't be included.

That's what I'm trying to accomplish, I'm just having a hard time locking down how to actually do it.

Answer (score 2):

### Theory

It might have been hard to word for you, but is actually quite clear what you are trying to accomplish.

A shortcode is a good way to insert dynamic content into a page (or post), the point at which your idea fails is the notion of a "dynamic shortcode".

Use the shortcode to insert the form into your content and have the callback handle what happens after submission.

Familiarize yourself with [how forms are handled in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php) and with the [difference between HTTP-POST and HTTP-GET](http://www.diffen.com/difference/GET_(HTTP)_vs_POST_(HTTP)) ([Resource 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get), [Resource 3](http://webdesign.about.com/od/forms/a/get-and-post-requests.htm)).

### Practice

Take the following as a proof of concept, rather than a copy/paste-ready solution:

Shortcode:
`[wpse_161632_sports_selection_form]`

PHP:

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: WPSE_161632
Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/161632/
Description: Shortcode form handler example
Version: 1.0
Author: Johannes Pilkahn
License: GPL3
*/

/*  Copyright 2014  Johannes Pilkahn

    This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 3, as
    published by the Free Software Foundation.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
    Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
*/


if ( ! class_exists( 'WPSE_161632' ) ) :

class WPSE_161632 {

    /**
     * Form handler
     *
     * @since 1.0
     * @access public
     * @see constructor
     */
    public function form_handler( $atts = '' )
    {
        // only relevant if the SC is supposed to have extra parameters
        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'example_attribute' => 1 
        ), $atts ) );

        if ( ( isset( $_POST['types'] ) ) {
            foreach( $_POST['types'] as $type ) {
                // do something
            }
            $this->output( true );
        } else {
            $this->output( false );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Outputs the form
     *
     * @since 1.0
     * @access public
     * @param bool $output
     */
    public function output( $submitted )
    {
        $options = array(
            array(
                'value' => 'skateboarding'
                'label' => __( 'Skateboarding', 'your-text-domain' )
            ),
            array(
                'value' => 'basketball'
                'label' => __( 'Basketball', 'your-text-domain' )
            ),
            array(
                'value' => 'hockey'
                'label' => __( 'Hockey', 'your-text-domain' )
            )
        );

        if ( $submitted ) {
            echo __( 'The form has been submitted!', 'your-text-domain' );
        }

        echo '<form action="#" method="post">';

        foreach ( $options as $option ) {
            echo '<input type="checkbox" '
                . 'value="' . $option['value'] . '" '
                . 'name="types[]" '
                . 'id="types_' . $option['value'] . '"';

            if ( $submitted && in_array( $option['value'], $_POST['types'] ) ) {
                echo ' checked="checked"';
            }

            echo ' /><label for="types_' . $option['value'] . '">'
                . $option['label'] . '</label>';
        }
        echo '</form>';
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @since 1.0
     * @access public
     */
    public function __construct() {
        add_shortcode(
            'wpse_161632_sports_selection_form',
            array( $this, 'form_handler' )
        );
    }

}

endif; // class exists

$wpse_161632 = new WPSE_161632;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

on click of your "Insert Shortcode" button, you'll want to use JavaScript/jQuery to see which checkboxes are checked, from which you'll create the Shortcode. after the shortcode is created, use `window.send_to_editor('[shortcode]')`.

something like this in all:

```
$("#insert-shortcode").on('click',function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var show = '';
    $(".checkboxes").each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked"))
            show += $(this).val() + ",";
    });
    window.send_to_editor('[shortcode show="' + show.substring(0,(show.length-1)) + '"]');
});
```

not tested, but something like that should work. of course, adjust the selectors to your specific names. I made an assumption on several things, so if I skipped over a portion that you need further explaining, just let us know.

Comment: Shortcodes are interpreted by PHP on the server side before serving the page to the client. How would JS/jQuery (or any other form of client side scripting) inserting a shortcode accomplish anything?

Comment: @JohannesPille from what I understood from the OP, you were asking how to generate the shortcode. your answer is quite thorough. up voted. waiting to see which was the actual question.

Comment: Caleb, please comment on the question if you are unclear what the actual question is. Also please familiarize yourself with the editor buttons and how code is formatted. I don't want to edit each and every one of your answers. Thank you.

Comment: @kaiser I had no reason to doubt what the question was, until Johannes answered differently. and I'm responding on iOS app: doesn't seem to be very many buttons. will take a look on desktop when I can.

Comment: Just intend code with 4 spaces. Then you got the right formatting.

Comment: tried that; didn't stick. :-/